# Facing issue while deserialization of JSON to object in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

I am facing issue while deserialization the JSON to object in my springboot application.
I am having code as below :-

```
public interface IStatus{

}

@JsonTypeName("internal")
public enum InternalStatus implements IStatus{
 INTERNAL_1,
 INTERNAL_2

}
@JsonTypeName("external")
public enum ExternalStatus implements IStatus{
 EXTERNAL_1,
 EXTERNAL_2
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
      include = As.PROPERTY, 
      property = "status")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = InternalStatus.class, name = "internal"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ExternalStatus.class, name = "external")
    })

@Setter
@Getter
public class Response{
 IStatus status;
}
```

and my json corresponding to Response class is {status:"EXTERNAL_1"}

**error details as below:-**

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class IStatus]: missing type id property 'status'

Comment: What is the “issue”? Please paste the exception message and other details which you think might be helpful.

Comment: Error details added.

Comment: Is this during serialisation or deserialisation?

Comment: During deserialization. Thanks!! I am correcting my problem statement